# MySQL: Syntax error when creating a trrigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, innodb

I am simply trying to insert a row into a parent table if the row doesn't exist in the parent table. I am getting "Statement incomplete. Expecting ';'" on the "INSERT INTO" line.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SellsInsertAlcoholAdd 
AFTER INSERT ON Sells
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.`Alcohol name` NOT IN
        (SELECT `Alcohol name` FROM Alcohol))
    THEN INSERT INTO Alcohol VALUES(NEW.`Alcohol Name`, NEW.`Type`, NEW.ABV, NEW.Manufacturer);
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unnecessarily getting all the `Alcohol name` values, and then checking for the `NEW` value within it. Instead, you can change to using [`NOT EXISTS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html).

You also need to change `DELIMITER` to something else (other than `;`) at the beginning. At the end, redefine it back to `;`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER SellsInsertAlcoholAdd 
AFTER INSERT ON Sells
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Alcohol 
                  WHERE `Alcohol name` = NEW.`Alcohol name`) THEN
      INSERT INTO Alcohol 
      VALUES(NEW.`Alcohol Name`, NEW.`Type`, NEW.ABV, NEW.Manufacturer);
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Fixed. I wasn't aware of the proper use of delimiter, I'll read more up on that. Thank you!

Comment: @LeoScarano do consider marking as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)

Comment: Will do! 5 min left haha

Comment: I am getting a "Unkown column 'Alcohol name' in "NEW" error. Any idea how to fix? It's been reported as a fixed mysql bug so I'm assumming my syntax is incorrect.

Comment: @LeoScarano share the table structure for both the tables. I feel that your columns names are different

Comment: Fixed. The primary key I was referencing was named differently. Just getting the hang of SQL. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore (in addition to Madhur's Answer), you don't need any of the `IF`.  Simply do `INSERT IGNORE ...`.  (This assumes that `Alcohol name` is `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY`.)